# How to create image views inside onActivityResult method in Android?

Tags: android, imageview, onactivityresult

I want to dynamically create image views inside the `onActivityResult` method.

If i define my `ImageView` like this: `imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);` works perfectly with this code:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();

        StorageReference photoStorageReference = storageReference.child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
        photoStorageReference.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Uri downloadUri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                Picasso.with(StorageActivity.this).load(downloadUri).fit().centerCrop().into(imageView);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But if i create the image views inside the `onActivityResult` method like this:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();

        StorageReference photoStorageReference = storageReference.child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
        photoStorageReference.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Uri downloadUri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
                linearLayout.addView(imageView);
                Picasso.with(StorageActivity.this).load(downloadUri).fit().centerCrop().into(imageView);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The image views are not displayed. I tried to create programmatically those image views in the `onCreate` method, but same problem. Nothing is displayed. If i create in stead of `ImageView`, buttons, the buttons are correctly displayed. What is wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to specify the LayoutParameters for the newly added view. Like below

```
imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: I have added the `LayoutParams` but same result, nothing is displayed.

Comment: did you set the ImageView with an actual image?

Comment: Yes, i have set `imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image);` and also nothing was displayed.

Comment: thats weird, maybe check your layout file, ImageView could be off the screen. Or you can try setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, 200)); and set a background color to see if it displays

Comment: You were right, the `ImageView` was out of the screen. I have added 2 lines of code: `LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(350, 350);` and `params .gravity = Gravity.START;`. Thanks you so much!